# how to use sum and groupBy in laravel consoletvs charts

Tags: php, laravel

```php
$sumBrpro = DB::table('productions')
              ->select([DB::raw('sum(montant_pro) as totalpro'),'branche'])
              ->groupBy('branche')
              ->get();
```

How can I pass a different value in consoletvs charts, this throws errors at index-> ​​branch.
thank you for your help

```php
foreach($sumBrpro as $index){
      $chartbr = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
                       ->title("production")
                       ->labels($index->branche)
                       ->values($index->totalpro)
                       ->dimensions(1000,500)
                       ->responsive(true);
}
```

Vue

````
<div>
                    {!! $chartbr->html() !!}
                </div>```
````

Comment: Post your `resources/views/graph.blade.php` code, the error is thrown there upon the call to `$variable->count()` where `$variable` is not a collection

Comment: nothing in your question is related to the error in the title. Also, it's not clear what is you're asking.

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: @CaddyDZ it is not $variable->count() error. In the case you described, there would be an error "Call to undefined method count()".  It is count($variable) error appeared in php 7.2. Most likely author calling simple php function count using null variable as argument.

Comment: count($string) depracted you should use count($array),if you check count of string PHP give you error from 7 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the usage of the `Charts` facade, I'm assuming you're using version 5.x the of [consoletvs/charts](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts) package.

This package expects arrays as arguments to the `labels()` and `values()` methods. In the `render()` method that is eventually called, the values you passed into the `labels()` and `values()` methods will be passed into `count()`, so if they're not countable, you'll get an error (in PHP >= 7.2).

Update your code to pass in arrays to the `labels()` and `values()` methods.

```
foreach ($sumBrpro as $index) {
    $chartbr = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
        ->title("production")
        ->labels([$index->branche])
        ->values([$index->totalpro])
        ->dimensions(1000,500)
        ->responsive(true);
}
```

However, I assume you're trying to create one chart where all the `branche`s are labels and all the `totalpro`s are values. In that case you're looking more for something like this:

```
$chartbr = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
    ->title("production")
    ->labels($sumBrpro->pluck('branche')->all())
    ->values($sumBrpro->pluck('totalpro')->all())
    ->dimensions(1000,500)
    ->responsive(true);
```

Comment: votre code de fonction mais juste que cela me retourne la dernière ligne. J'essaie d'utiliser `$chartbr[]` mais au `render()` niveau il ne peut pas gérer un tableau,`@patricus` `@foreach($chart as $chart)
                    <div>
                        {!! $chart->render('labels', 'values') !!}
                    </div>
                @endforeach`

Comment: @landes I've made an update to my answer that is probably more what you're looking for. However, for future reference, the SO site is primarily english. I saw your comment in english before it was updated to french, otherwise I wouldn't know what you're asking for.

Comment: `foreach($sumBrpro as $sumBrpro){
            $lab [] = $sumBrpro->branche;
            $val [] = $sumBrpro->totalpro;
        }`that's what I tried to walk `->labels($lab)
                    ->values($val)` Thanks for your help @patricus